# asp.net mvc4 razor pass view model to helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass view model to my html helper/
I have tried

```
 public static string GenerateFullTable(this HtmlHelper helper, IEnumerable<CarsViewModel> model)
        {
```

But I dont know which model would be.

Does it possible to make universal helper which gets would get different view models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called Generics.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

**Edit:**

Here's one example...

```
public static string GenerateFullTable<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, IEnumerable<T> model)
{
    ...
}
```

You can further constrain T to be of a specific type or inheriting certain interface, maybe something like this:

```
public static string GenerateFullTable<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, IEnumerable<T> model) where T : MyModelsInterface
{

}
```

But that depends on your needs. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: How i can get T for next use??

Comment: @Acid ?? Pardon? T is a generic type, means you can substitute it by anything that isn't forbidden by the specified constraint.