# C# get IEnumerable type and use it in list

Tags: c#, ienumerable, asp.net-mvc-4

I have `IEnumerable<object> Value`. Can I get model type and then declare same type List?

for example i got IEnumerable then want to declare `List<cars> lst = new List<cars>`

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to declare a variable with the same static type as the runtime type of another variable?  It should be obvious this isn't possible.  I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do.  Can you clarify?

Comment: You might just be looking for `Value.ToList()` (a LINQ extension method).

Comment: Do you really have an `IEnumerable<object>`, or do you have an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` may be any type?

Comment: Related to the other comments: How do you define *model type*?

Comment: Yes i have <object> I want to make method which gets different models and than changes some data. I dont know how i can do this

Comment: Are you assuming all object are of the same type? Maybe you are looking for `List<IVehicle>`?

Comment: Please see my older question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968560/asp-net-mvc4-razor-pass-view-model-to-helper/10968584#comment14322618_10968584

Comment: @Acid, as I've said in that question, use generics, not object type. Have you done at least a basic research on generics from that website I've provided a link for? Highly doubt that and I don't understand why you create multiple questions about the same matter, especially when the first question has been already answered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Template types are determined at compile-time.  However, you could try declaring it as

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>(value);
```

You wouldn't get true type safety but you could access the properties in your form  without using reflection:

```
foreach(dynamic d in list)  // assuming the list is a list of cars
{
    This car is a <%= d.Model %>.
}
```